# Silverstripe create a simple static HTML page

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do I with Silverstrip just create a plain HTML page ?

I am trying to add a page, then edit HTML to put in my own script tags etc, and won't let me.

Answer (score 2):

i think you're talking about editing the page templates (mysite/templates/Page.ss), right? a common mistake is not flushing the template cache whenever you change a template. just add `?flush=1` to your page url to do so.

also see the docs on [URL Variable Tools](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/urlvariabletools) for further information on this.

additionally, in case you don't want to have pages in the cms, you might be interested in [this tutorial on ssbits](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2011/controllers-instead-of-pages/) to bypass the cms and render arbitrary html code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple page in /themes/blackcandy/templates/MyPage.ss

This page template will be used to render any page type of the same name. Try creating a new class in /mysite/code/MyPage.php that extends Page. Then dev/build and view create a new MyPage page object in the CMS. That page should use the MyPage.ss template.